# How to set Proxy configuration?

Tags: apt

Below are the instruction I have to follow for setting up cloudera.  I am confused about the below on ubuntu 12.04.

```
On Debian/Ubuntu systems, add the following property to /etc/apt/apt.conf:
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://server:port/";
```

Here is the contents of /etc/apt

```
/etc/apt# ls
apt.conf.d  preferences.d  sources.list  sources.list~  sources.list.d  trustdb.gpg  trusted.gpg  trusted.gpg~  trusted.gpg.d
```

There is no apt.conf file.  Do I create one?

Also...do I place this line exact in the file?

```
  Acquire::http::Proxy "http://server:port/";
```

Or do I have to fill in the blanks e.g.
     Acquire::http::Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:1234/";

Answer (score 4):

Simply create the file and add your content in it. See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#APT_configuration_file_method). Use `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf` for graphical edit, or `sudoedit /etc/apt/apt.conf` for console edit.

Regarding what you have to put in the configuration, you have to put the proxy address and its port (so fill in the blanks). If you do need a proxy, ofc.